# need a unique column to an existing query

Tags: mysql, database

I have a log table in mysql that looks like this:

```
table1

id  client_id  country   result
-------------------------------
1   323323     US        escalated
```

My current query is:

```
select country, count(country) as country_total 
    FROM table1
    WHERE result = 'escalated' 
    GROUP BY country 
    ORDER BY country_total 
    DESC LIMIT 5
```

results (which is exactly what i want) are:

```
 $VAR1 = [
      {
        'country' => 'US',
        'country_total' => '30'
      },
      {
        'country' => 'CN',
        'country_total' => '19'
      },
      {
        'country' => 'DE',
        'country_total' => '10'
      }
    ];
```

However, client_ids in the log table can have duplicates and I do not want duplicates in my result set. How can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `distinct`

```
SELECT country, count(distinct client_id) as country_total 
FROM table1
WHERE result = 'escalated' 
GROUP BY country 
ORDER BY country_total 
DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaaand it becomes so clear, because my brain fart has cleared. Thank you.